# How to SUM a column in an oracle apex collection

Tags: oracle, collections, oracle-apex

So I am trying to output the total of a column from a collection.

This is the first query I tried

```
select sum(C007),sum(C007) A FROM APEX_COLLECTIONS WHERE COLLECTION_NAME='PURCHASE'
```

This is the second query I tried

```
select sum(C005*C007),sum(C005*C007) A FROM APEX_COLLECTIONS WHERE COLLECTION_NAME='PURCHASE'
```

Both produce the same result which list out all the values in the column insted of suming them

Expected Results:

```
10
```

Actual Results:

```
2
2
2
2
2
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you did something wrong.

I created sample page; it contains a button (which will just submit the page) and an item which will display total (sum of collection's values). Item gets populated by a process which contains *everything* (for simplicity):

```
if not apex_collection.collection_exists('PURCHASE') then
   apex_collection.create_collection('PURCHASE');
end if;

apex_collection.add_member(
  p_collection_name => 'PURCHASE',
  p_c001            => 'Little',
  p_c007            => 100);              --> 100 ...
apex_collection.add_member(
  p_collection_name => 'PURCHASE',
  p_c001            => 'Foot',
  p_c007            => 200);              --> ... + 200 = 300

select sum(c007)
  into :P7_TOTAL
  from apex_collections
  where collection_name = 'PURCHASE';
```

When ran (and after button was pressed), item's value is - as expected - `300`.

[image]